# Understanding the posix interprocess semaphore

Tags: c++, posix, semaphore

According to my understanding, a semaphore should be usable across related processes without it being placed in shared memory. If so, why does the following code deadlock?

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

using namespace std;

static int MAX = 100;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int retval;
  sem_t mutex;

  cout << sem_init(&mutex, 1, 0) << endl;

  pid_t pid = fork();

  if (0 == pid) {
    //     sem_wait(&mutex);
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
      cout << i << ",";
    }
    cout << endl;
    sem_post(&mutex);

  } else if(pid > 0) {
    sem_wait(&mutex);
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
      cout << i << ",";
    }
    cout << endl;
    //     sem_post(&mutex);
    wait(&retval);

  } else {
    cerr << "fork error" << endl;
    return 1;
  }

//   sem_destroy(&mutex);

  return 0;
}
```

When I run this on Gentoo/Ubuntu Linux, the parent hangs. Apparently, it did not receive the post by child. Uncommenting sem_destroy won't do any good. Am I missing something?

**Update 1:**
This code works

```
mutex = (sem_t *) mmap(NULL, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, 0, 0);
if (!mutex) {
  perror("out of memory\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

Thanks,
Nilesh.

Comment: Could you add a tag for the language you are using? I would guess c or c++, but it'd aid in searachability.

Answer (score 5):

The wording in [the manual page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sem_init.3.html) is kind of ambiguous.

> If pshared is nonzero, then the semaphore is shared between processes,
>   and **should be located in a region of shared memory**.
>
> Since a child created by fork(2) inherits its parent's memory
>   mappings, it can also access the semaphore.

Yes, but **it still has to be in a shared region**. Otherwise the memory simply gets copied with the usual [CoW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) and that's that.

You can solve this in at least two ways:

- Use `sem_open("my_sem", ...)`
- Use `shm_open` and `mmap` to create a shared region

Comment: Thanks for you response! Here is what I tried without sucess...
    if ((mutex = sem_open("mysemaphore", O_CREAT, 0644, 0)) == SEM_FAILED) {
 cerr << "semaphore initilization error" << endl;
 return 1;
      }

      
      pid_t pid = fork();
      
      if (0 == pid) {
 /*
 if ((mutex = sem_open("mysemaphore", 0, 0644, 0)) == SEM_FAILED) {
   cerr << "semaphore initilization error" << endl;
   return 1;
 }
 */
 cout << "here1" << endl;
 sem_post(mutex);
      } else if(pid > 0) {
 sem_wait(mutex);
 cout << "here2" << endl;
 wait(&retval);
      }
the output:
here2
here1

Comment: Ack! the formatting is messed up in the comment, don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Rather than a named semaphore, I would `mmap` anonymous shared memory and `sem_init` it process-shared prior to forking. This way you don't have to worry about leaving around a named resource you have to clean up.

Comment: @R..: true. However, that will let you use it only between related processes, or you have to pass the pointer towards the shared memory through a message. You comment is correct in the question's context, as the OP asks for related processes. OTOH, a named resource can be re-used later, if one aims for synchronization of unrelated processes.

Answer (score 3):

An excellent article on this topic, for future passers-by:

http://blog.superpat.com/2010/07/14/semaphores-on-linux-sem_init-vs-sem_open/