Process synchronisation for different processes not working with 2 semaphores
I am trying to learn process synchronization , I am trying semaphore,to print odd and even numbers alternatively using 2 processes , one process will execute odd function and another process will execute even function.
My code snippet is as below:
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

sem_t s,s1;

void odd(int& value)
{
    while (value<10)
    {
        if(sem_wait(&s) == 0)
        {
            cout << "odd thread: " <<" process id: "<< getpid() <<" thread id: "<< this_thread::get_id()<<" value: "<<value<<'\n';
            value++;
            sem_post(&s1);
        }
    }
}

void even(int& value)
{
    while (value<11)
    {
        if(sem_wait(&s1) == 0)
        {
            cout << "even thread: "<<" process id: "<< getpid() <<" thread id: "<< this_thread::get_id()<<" value: "<<value<<'\n';
            value++;
            sem_post(&s);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    int value = 1;
    //sem_t s,s1;
    sem_init(&s,0,1);
    sem_init(&s1,0,0);
    
    pid_t pid = fork();
    
    if(pid < 0)
        cout<<"Fork failed\n";
    else
    {
        if(pid)
        {
            cout<<"Parent process creating odd thread, parent process id: "<<getpid()<<'\n';
            odd(value);
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Child process creating even thread, child process id: "<<getpid()<<'\n';
            even(value);
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Only the parent process is able to execute odd function , Even function is not getting executed, sorry for asking a very basic question , but since I am beginner to C++ , I am facing this problem , please suggest if I am doing something wrong.
I was expecting that the parent and child process should be able to execute the respective odd and even functions

If you're a beginner in C++, I would not start out with interprocess (or any asyncrhonous kind of ) programming.   I am not familiar with linux, but to me it looks like you're not creating an inter-process mutex at all (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863571/understanding-the-posix-interprocess-semaphore)

@MarekR fork() creates a new process.

@MarekR, I was trying to create new processes using fork() , also as pointed out by wohlstad

I tried debugging the code, sem_post(&s1) is not signalling the semaphore s1, hence even function is not getting executed, I added breakpoint on "if(sem_wait(&s1) == 0)" , but could not understand the reason

Take a look on documentation your program has simple mistake for pshared (second argument of sem_init).

fork is not a C++ std function; nor is it a std C function. It's a POSIX function. C++ is the wrong tag for this question. Removing fork and using boost.interprocess or QProcess or some other 3rd party C++ interprocess library could make it relevant, but that requires good understanding of C++ basics,  such as object model, memory model, reference semantics, object lifetime and RAII... Just a lot of prerequisites about C++. Fix the tags to POSIX and C, or ask a question about C++ interprocess facilities.

@Marek R, I updated the semaphore as per documentation , updated code snippet(for success fork) is as below:
    if(pid)
    {
        cout<<"Parent process creating odd thread, parent process id: "<<getpid()<<'\n';
        s=sem_open(SEM_ID,O_CREAT|O_RDWR,S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR,0);
        sem_init(s,2,1);
        s1=sem_open(SEM_ID1,0);
        odd(value);
    }


@MarekR, else part of code is:
else
{
cout<<"Child process creating even thread, child process id: "<<getpid()<<'\n';
s=sem_open(SEM_ID,0);
s1=sem_open(SEM_ID1,O_CREAT|O_RDWR,S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR,0);
sem_init(s1,2,0);
even(value);
}
Still I am facing the same issue, am I missing something else ?

@Red.Wave The code in this question is very clearly C++, not C.

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica fork is not an option then. Even in the context of POSIX, that function has limitations(should not be invoked after thread creation). So, the mix with C++ makes it extremely error-prone.

@Red.Wave Where does this program create any threads?

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica the snippet is obviously stripped. Otherwise why #include <thread>?

@Red.Wave, I was just trying to get thread ids of threads executing even and odd function "this_thread::get_id()" , see the functions odd() and even(), it was just for learning

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica , I updated the code to have sem_open instead of sem_init , still the process synchronization is not working  the sem_t s1 is never getting signalled although I did it in the odd function , am I missing something ?

@MarekR , any further suggestions ? I replaced sem_init with sem_open as mentioned in previous comments, still s1 is not getting signalled

You are making a common C resource management mistake: your sem_wait and sem_post are invoked on different objects. Use RAII and create named semaphores as local(not global) objects, as private members of your proc_mutex class. Make sure to delete the move operations. After properly defining lock+ unlock members, you can use std::scoped_lock or std::unique_lock for safe locking.
